# How do I convert dateTime format in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format

Here is the

```
string date = "07-Feb-2020";
```

I'm unsure how to convert it to

```
"2020-02-07 00:00:00"
```

representation

Comment: Convert it to a DateTime via TryParse. Convert the DateTime back to a string via ToString.

Comment: Pretty similar to discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1438045/4636715

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ParseExact` into `DateTime` then format to the desired `string` representation:

```
  string date = "07-Feb-2020";

  string result = DateTime
    .ParseExact(date, "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Parse Exact

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-MMM-yyyy", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime:

```
 DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 10);
 Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");

 DateTimeOffset thisDate2 = new DateTimeOffset(2011, 6, 10, 15, 24, 16, 
                                          TimeSpan.Zero);
 Console.WriteLine("The current date and time: {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}", 
               thisDate2); 
 // The example displays the following output:
 //    Today is June 10, 2011.
 //    The current date and time: 06/10/11 15:24:16 +00:00
```

[Code is from Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

You can create any formatting you wish to do

Answer (score -3):

You must parse string to `DateTime` first. Then you can do `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`